# JIRA JQL: Finding cards that need an estimation

Tags: jira, jql

I try to filter for tasks that lack an estimation in Jira. Currently my query includes

```
originalEstimate is EMPTY
```

but that gives me also results that have sub tasks with estimations (so the summed up estimation would not be empty for that tasks). I want to filter them out but it looks like there is no summed `originalEstimate` available in JQL. Then I tried to exclude Jira cards which have sub-cards but I wasn't able to achieve that as well.

So maybe someone can help me to

- either include the estimation sum in the query
- or filter for cards without sub cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JIRA Original Estimate from parent and subtask are separated. When you check "include subtasks" checkbox it will roll up and display the estimates from subtasks, but that is for display only.

I don´t see how to do what you need in JQL, but If you have JIRA Script Runner addon you can use parentOf() to achieve your result: https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_subtasks

Or any other addon that extends JIRA´s JQL like ScriptRunner.

EDIT: Another approach with Script Runner is to define a Custom Field that will be set to 1 if all subtasks are not estimated, 0 otherwise. Then you can use this CF in your queries.